# Figure subnumbering 1a

Tags: floats, numbering, captions

I'm wondering how to give subnumberings like "2a" and "2b" for *separate* floats.  I know both the `subfigure` and `subcaption` packages do the subnumbering but they demand the subfigures be in a single `figure` environment.

For example, I'd be happy if I could find an environment `subfigures` like this:

```
\begin{subfigures}
\begin{figure}
  A figure comes here.
  \caption{\label{first}Caption text.} %--> Fig.1a
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  Another figure.
  \caption{\label{second}Caption text.} %--> Fig.1b
\end{figure}
\end{subfigures}
```

It's basically the same as AMS LaTeX's `subequations` environment.

The reason why I want to do this is that I can't decide how I should group my figures until much later in my writing process.  If I had an environment like the above, all I would have to do is to cut&paste `figure` environments or delete or add `subfigures` environments in order to reorganize my figures.

Since what I want is very similar to the `subequations` environment, I guess I can make my own `subfigures` environment after enough hacking, but I'm not much versed in TeX coding and am wondering if there is already a solution available.

Thanks for your help.

Ryo

Edit: Thank you all for your responses.  Mico asks: ‘Should the individual figure environments within a (still to be designed) subfigures environment be allowed to "float" and possibly end up on different pages . . . ?’ — Yes.  I just want *separate* floats to be numbered in the way I want and that's all.  Of course, if there be an option that controls the placement of the grouped figures, that would be a nice addition.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Should the individual `figure` environments within a (still to be designed) `subfigures` environment be allowed to "float" and possibly end up on different pages, or would they all have to be on the same page?

Answer (score 16):

The `subfloat` package offers exactly what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\begin{document}
\begin{subfigures}
\begin{figure}
  A figure comes here.
  \caption{\label{first}Caption text.} %--> Fig.1a
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  Another figure.
  \caption{\label{second}Caption text.} %--> Fig.1b
\end{figure}
\end{subfigures}
\end{document}
```

See also `subfloat` package documentation.

A different option would be using `\ContinuedFloat` offered by the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
% Mark continued floats as a, b, ...
\renewcommand\theContinuedFloat{\alph{ContinuedFloat}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \ContinuedFloat*
  A figure comes here.
  \caption{\label{first}Caption text.} %--> Fig.1a
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \ContinuedFloat
  Another figure.
  \caption{\label{second}Caption text.} %--> Fig.1b
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

See also `caption` package documentation, section "Continued Floats".

The result is exactly the same for both solutions:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you!  I've just now confirmed your "subfloat" solution does exacty what I wanted.  I was correct in assuming that somebody had already come up with a solution and I also correctly predicted the name ("subfigures") given to the feature!  The ContinuedFloat solution will also be useful when I use other features of the caption package.  Thanks again.

Comment: `subfloat` even works more generally: you can use `subtable` on tabulars that aren't in a floating environment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very basic idea- define your `subfigures` environment as follows

```
\newenvironment{subfigures}{\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter\alph{figure}}}{}
```

This changes `\thefigure` at the beginning of the environment- `LaTeX` will keep this redefinition local to this environment, as demonstrated in the MWE below.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: on}
\documentclass{report}

\newenvironment{subfigures}{\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter\alph{figure}}}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

\section{Inside of subfigures}
\begin{subfigures}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        A figure comes here.
        \caption{Caption text.} %--> Fig.1a
        \label{first}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        Another figure.
        \caption{Caption text.} %--> Fig.1b
        \label{second}
    \end{figure}
    \ref{first} and \ref{second}
\end{subfigures}

\section{Outside of subfigures}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    A figure comes here.
    \caption{Caption text.} 
    \label{firstagain}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    Another figure.
    \caption{Caption text.}
    \label{secondagain}
\end{figure}
\ref{firstagain} and \ref{secondagain}

\end{document}
```

Comment: On the basis of your ideas, I've been able to achieve my goal! But, I'm new to stackexchange and don't know what's the best way to present my solution and ask for feedbacks. Should I edit my own question? or should I post an "answer" or should I use these comment boxes?