# Table subnumbering 1a, 1b, etc

Tags: floats, numbering

I have a table that is too big to fit on a page without shrinking the text to unreadable sizes. As a result, I have split it in to two. I can't use longtable to do this automatically as I am also using `\resizebox` to control the text size.

Is it possible to set the table numbers to 1a and 1b rather than 1 and 2?

Comment: Take a look at the `subfloat` package. See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118192/figure-subnumbering-1a/118220#118220

Comment: If you haven't read the `subfloat` documentation, then it is not clear from the answer at the link above that you need to use `\begin{subtables} \end{subtables}` for tables instead of subfigures

Comment: `subtable` from `subfloat` even works on tabulars that aren't in a floating environment. Excellent surprise!

Answer (score 3):

Since this seems like a one-off deal, just update the `table` counter and add the "sub-counter":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}% Just for this example
%\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Table before}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}a}
  %\renewcommand{\theHtable}{\thetable A}% To keep hyperref happy
  \caption{First caption}\label{first}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \addtocounter{table}{-1}
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}b}
  %\renewcommand{\theHtable}{\thetable B}% To keep hyperref happy
  \caption{Second caption}\label{second}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Table after}
\end{table}
See Tables~\ref{first} and~\ref{second}.
\end{document}
```

The lines commented out are just in case you use [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). It adds a modification to `\theHtable`, in order to avoid duplicate destinations from stepping the `table` counter backwards.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not actually a one-off deal.  I have a whole bunch of tables in a large document and three of them have been split in two.

Comment: @thornate: That's only 6 modifications; not that major. Either way, Alex's link provides a more generic approach to solving your problem.